# Set a specific Cell of a DataGridView to an alignment of "Left to Right"

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime-format, right-to-left

I have a `DataGridView` with right to left align (because the language of the program is Persian), but some specific columns like `clmn_Email` should be left to right and the column of a register `DateTime` also should be left to right.

`DateTime` in RTL align is shown like

> ب.ظ1397/07/07 08:32:14

but it should be displayed like

> 1397/07/07 08:32:14 ب.ظ

Anyway, I go to the `Collection`and then to `defaultCellStyle` and change the alignment to "middle left", but it doesn't work at all and nothing changed.

Can anyone help me? (I didn't find a question like this. If it's repetitious, please send me the link of the question).

Comment: Try setting the `DataGridCellStyle.FormatProvider` to `FormatProvider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Or to a specific culture which has the Date format you require. `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")`, for example

Comment: Or, more simple, define the `DataGridViewCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss yyyy/MM/dd"` and using it as `DefaultCellStyle` format. It will be reversed in a RTL language.

Comment: @Jimi tnx for ur replay , i tried do somethings in `frmclient.Designer.cs`  like that u said but unfortunately i didn't success

Comment: This depends on how you create your DGV columns. Their `FormatProvider` should be set upon creation. While the `Format` string can be set at a different time. If you set `[DataGridViewCell].Style.Format = "hh:mm:ss yyyy/MM/dd";`, the RTL ime format will render it as `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"`. If you then set `.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight`, the ime format will render it left-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.
If DataGridView is Right to Left, for setting a column alignment Left to Right should go to `properties >collection > DefultCellStyle> set Alignment = middleRight` (i except this option set the alignment Right to Left but it works reverse !!).
for that problem of displaying datetime i do this :

```
public static string ReversePersianDateTime(PersianDateTime pdt)
    {
        return pdt.DayName + " " + pdt.Hour + ":" + pdt.Minute + ":" + pdt.Second + " " + pdt.Year + "/" + pdt.Month + "/" + pdt.Day;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, add the LTR control character to the beginning of the original data.
char.Parse ("\ u200E") + original data ("ب.ظ 1397/07/07 08:32:14")